# python_terraform is not taking s3 backend

Tags: python, automation, terraform

As I am using python_terraform module to apply terraform.  I am creating a terraform backend file in python and running init, but after applying to terraform the state file is created locally

```
from python_terraform import *
import shutil
import os
var_file = "test_sqs_name"
print(var_file)
# creating the terraform.tf  file
backend_file = open("/Users/ankit/workplace/events-infra/terraform/formations/test/sqs/terraform.tf", "w+")
backend_file.write("""terraform { 
  backend \"s3\" {
    key            = \"formations/project/sqs/dev/%s\" 
    bucket         = \"terraform-backend-dev\"
    dynamodb_table = \"terraform-backend-dev\"
    region         = \"us-west-2\"
    profile        = \"engdev\"
    }
}""" % (var_file))

try:
    shutil.rmtree("/Users/ankit/workplace/events-infra/terraform/formations/test/sqs/.terraform")
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: %s : %s" % (
        "/Users/ankit/workplace/events-infra/terraform/formations/test/sqs/.terraform", e.strerror))
tf = Terraform(working_dir='/Users/ankit/workplace/events-infra/terraform/formations/test/sqs',
               terraform_bin_path='/usr/local/bin/terraform-0-12-12',
               var_file='/Users/ankit/workplace/events-infra/backend/test.us-west-2-' + var_file + '.tfvars',

               )
tf.init(
        dir_or_plan='/Users/ankit/workplace/events-infra/terraform/formations/test/sqs',
)
plan_value = tf.plan(no_color=IsFlagged, refresh=False, capture_output=True)
print(plan_value[1])
approve = {"auto-approve": True}
print(tf.apply(capture_output=True, auto_approve=True, skip_plan=True, **approve)[1])
```

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your Python code here but it looks like you are unnecessarily escaping the quotes in the content in your backend file. What does it look like when you open the file after running that script? Also is there a good reason for you to be using this Python script rather than just using the Terraform CLI? You aren't actually doing anything dynamic here and it looks like it's just adding complexity. If you are new to Terraform I'd strongly suggest learning Terraform directly first.

Comment: The backend file is created as expected but the problem is when I am applying the terraform it is not taking the backend file instead it is creating the state file locally and not sending it to s3. I have to apply to terraform for 60 files so I am creating the backend file  dynamically  base on sqs name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is being kept open until python exits, which is likely interfering with Terraform reading it.